# $(document).on() functions not working with Safari

Tags: jquery

I am a web developing newbie and have just finished building my first website. I am testing it on various platforms and have found that on Safari (phone and tablet, have not tried it on desktop) the commands relating to $(document).on( ) are not working at all.

The same code is running perfectly on Chrome, IE and FireFox so I guess it is a compatibility issue?

Is there a quick fix? Or am I just doing it wrong!?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //load home as default
    $("#main").load("pages/home.htm");

    //events for nav bar
    $("#home_button").click(function() {
        $("#main").load("pages/home.htm");
    });
    $("#news_button").click(function() {
        $("#main").load("pages/news.htm");
    });
    $("#about_button").click(function() {
        $("#main").load("pages/about.htm");
    });
    $("#contact_button").click(function() {
        $("#main").load("pages/contact.htm");
    });

    //events for home section - note this is a bit more tricky as the home page is being added dynamically by the code above ...

    $(document).on("mouseenter", "#news_link", function() {
        $(this).css("opacity","0.5");
    });
    $(document).on("mouseleave", "#news_link", function() {
        $(this).css("opacity","1");
    });
    $(document).on("click","#news_link", function() {
        $("#main").load("pages/news.htm");
    });


    $(document).on("mouseenter", "#about_link", function() {
        $(this).css("opacity","0.5");
    });
    $(document).on("mouseleave", "#about_link", function() {
        $(this).css("opacity","1");
    });
    $(document).on("click","#about_link", function() {
        $("#main").load("pages/about.htm");
    });

    //about - contact me link function

    $(document).on("mouseenter", ".contact", function() {
        $(this).css("opacity","0.5");
    });
    $(document).on("mouseleave", ".contact", function() {
        $(this).css("opacity","1");
    });
    $(document).on("click",".contact", function() {
        $("#main").load("pages/contact.htm");
    });     

});
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle so we can test?

Comment: I have to admit I have no idea how to do that Jay.. I am looking into it now. Is it a fairly simple process?

Comment: Yes - place some markup and code, then choose your jquery version. Click 'run' and perform your actions. It'll give us something to look at. BTW, are there any errors reported by Safari?

Comment: Note that mobile devices don't typically have mice to trigger events like `mouseenter`. They use [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent#Touch_event_types) like `touchstart`.

Comment: Jay - I don't have access to the console becasue I am testing on ipad, but it is not showing an error. Yes Jonathon I was not expecting the mouse functions to work but the click listener should still work I think. It certainly works on Android on my phone in a chrome browser and in the Android browser. -- I will try and set up a jsfiddle ...

Comment: @SamRedway What types of elements are these events being bound to? If the element isn't by default associated with interaction, [Mobile Safari may need some additional cues to enable `click`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click#Safari_Mobile).

Comment: You need to include the relevant HTML in the OP.

Comment: Actually it is really irrelevant the HTML code Sparky, I think it might just convolute the post. The same solution would apply to any element that is not inherently clickable (i.e. not a button or form type element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Jonathon that was exactly the problem. For the benefit of anyone else coming across this problem:

Safari was having a problem attaching a listener to an element it did not believe was 'clickable' so I simply had to add a dummy onClick to the element. I added this code:

```
style="cursor:pointer" 
onClick=""
```

And it is now working as expected on Iphone and Ipad.